# Error Streaming Movies to PS3 (From Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, ps3

I have been streaming downloaded movies to PS3 for a while now but suddenly the new movies that I downloaded don't work. It comes up with an error that reads "Media Server Error: A network error has occurred. (00000000). I am currently using Windows 7 have only started having this problem within the last couple days.

Comment: Is the folder the videos are in shared?

Comment: What are you using to stream? What format are the movies in? What video codec is used?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the time this error comes up because the folder they're in isn't shared. Occasionally though it can be caused by windows media player losing sync with device. If the latter is the case you just need to resync it.

An even less likely culprit is the firewall. Some people will tell you to turn it off but this is NOT necessary. Just check it make sure sharing is properly enabled.

Comment: How would I go about resyncing it? The new movies are in the same folder as the old movies and the old movies play fine....its just the new movies that don't.

Comment: Click on your library tab and then click on sync.you should then see an icon in the box that says "unknown device". Click on it and allow the connection. More troubling though is that the old movies STILL play.

Comment: Where is the library tab? Is it on the computer or on the playstation?

Comment: It's in media player on your PC.

Comment: I don't see the library tab in my media player. Maybe I have a different version?

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with my homegroup (Windows 7) settings for an hour, this is what I found.

1. Changed all permissions on the folder and files to allow "home user" to control them.
2. Changed the "File sharing connections to enable 40 or 50 bit encryption".
3. Open media streaming options and delete multiple instances of any devices in the "All Networks" list.
4. Check and be sure your old files still play via Windows Media Server on your PS3.
5. While streaming the old video, disconnect the server by turning off the wireless network on the host computer till the video and audio stop completely.
6. Turn the connection back on and wait for all servers to reconnect.
7. Try playing again...
8. Voila!

If it doesn't work, restart the PS3 and try again.

Remember, I have no idea which of these steps actually did the trick.